# Does the closure of the set of all irreducible elements always equal the whole set?

Tags: order-theory, universal-algebra

Let $X$ denote a set and $\mathrm{cl}$ denote a [finitary closure operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator#Closure_operators_in_algebra) on its powerset. Call $x \in X$ *irreducible* iff for all $A \subseteq X$ we have that if $x \in \mathrm{cl}(A)$, then $x \in A$.

**Question.** Does the closure of the set of all irreducible elements necessarily equal $X$?

I think the answer should be "trivially, yes" but for some reason I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be enough irreducible elements, as you've defined them.

Take the example mentioned at the article you linked, of forming ${cl}(A)$ as the span of a subset $A$ of a vector space $X$.  Then no $x \in X$ is irreducible as we can find a set $A$ depending on $x$ such that $x$ is not in $A$ but is in the span of $A$.

In this case the set of irreducible elements is empty, and the closure of the empty set is {$0$}, which need not be all of $X$.

Comment: Yep, nice. When you say "there may not be enough irreducible elements, as you've defined them," are you meaning to suggest there is a better definition?

Comment: It more reflects my uncertainty as to your purpose in choosing the definition, esp. if you were expecting a "trivial" resolution.  My wild speculation would be to aim at defining, not irreducible elements, but irreducible sets and try to show $X$ is the union of these, e.g. an *irreducible set* is $A$ s.t. no proper subset of $A$ has the same closure as $A$.  In the vector space context this leads to the notion of linearly independent sets, and the union of all these would be $X\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: I like where you're going with this; the basic idea of moving to subsets rather than elements is usually a good one. However, note that your definition of "irreducible set" doesn't reduce to my definition of "irreducible element" in the case where we identify $x$ with $\{x\}$. So I think your definition should be termed "independent subset" and viewed as an entirely different (although related) concept. To give an example, in a non-trivial vector space $V$, no $x \in V$ is irreducible, however every non-zero $\{x\}$ is independent.

Comment: Anyway I'll let you know if I have any more thoughts about the matter, and I hope you'll do the same.